# Angular atribuir dados de uma requisição POST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requisição

Boas pessoal eu tenho o seguinte código

```
app.controller('lista', function($http){
        $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //this.feriados = <?php echo json_encode($feriados->feriados); ?>;

        this.feriados = {};

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '../controllers/feriados.php',
            data: "op=listaTodos"
        }).then(function (respondse){
            this.feriados = response.data;
            console.log(this.feriados);
        },function (error){

        });


       });
```

O meu problema é que na impressão para a console os "feriados" aparecem, mas se fizer `<div ng-controller="lista as l"> {{ l.feriados }}</div>` vejo que a variável mantém o valor `{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o erro :)

Está na atribuição à variável `this`, julgei mal o seu **alcance**.

Basta adicionar dentro do controlador

```
var controller = this;
```

E depois atribuir a resposta a esta variável

```
controller.feriados = resposta;
```